# How to get system up / boot time in milliseconds in C++ in cross-platform (it should work in windows / IOS / Android / MAC)

Tags: c++, c++11

I have written a framework dll in c++ which is getting used in cross- platforms like windows, Mac, Android , IOS. I need to implement one API get_time_since_boot_milli_seconds() which will give me time in milliseconds since boot of system cross - platform (windows / mac / IOS / Android).

I have found function like GetTickCount64() but it works only in windows. Similarly there are function which works only in Mac. I had tried std::chrono , but did not get any relevant API.

I expect standard std C++ function which could give me time in milliseconds since boot up in every platform.

Comment: AFAIK, std has nothing to offer here. And the concept of "time since boot" turns out to be quite vague once you get down to fine details. Does waking up from sleep count as "boot"? What about time spent in hybernation - should it be counted or not? Macbooks can silently go from sleep to hybernate...

Comment: @IgorG: Thanks for your reply. For me no. Only start of machine from shut down is consider as boot. Do you mean we need to implement this API for each platform ? I think might be c++ 11 / C++ 14 has something to offer ?

Comment: The best C++11 has to offer is for you to implement your own `boot_clock::now()` for each platform which returns `std::chrono::time_point<boot_clock, std::chrono::milliseconds>`.  This will give you a portable ABI which interoperates with the rest of the `std::chrono` infrastructure.  On some platforms, that implementation may be as simple as `return time_point{duration_cast<milliseconds>(steady_clock::now())};`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Wouldn't that `duration_cast` need a duration rather than a `time_point` or does that cast work under certain circumstances? I'm asking because I just wanted precisely this uptime thingy myself and had to do `duration_cast<milliseconds>(steady_clock::now() - time_point<steady_clock>{})` on my platform.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Good catch.  What you have looks good.  Another way to spell that is `duration_cast<milliseconds>(steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch())`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant That's even nicer - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think none of std timers provide guaranteed uptime. So yes, you'd have to to it yourself.

**Windows:**

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)
uint64_t    uptime_milli = GetTickCount64();
#else
uint32_t    uptime_milli = GetTickCount();
#endif
```

The solution above should include sleep / suspend and hibernate time.
Depending on your range of supported OS versions, you may want to replace compile-time `#if` with run-time test whether `GetTickCount64` is available in "kernel32.dll".

Alternative solution is to use `QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime()`. It does NOT include sleep / suspend / hibernate time, but it is more reliable (in a sense that a user can't cheat and interfere).

---

**Newer Posix-based platforms:**

```
struct timespec     up;
int                 err = clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, &up);
if (err != 0)
    HandleError();
uint64_t      uptime_nano = up.tv_sec * 1000000000 + up.tv_nsec;
```

Interval returned by this function should have sleep and suspend time included.

---

**Older Linux** (around glibc 2.3.6, can't check to make sure):

```
struct timespec   up;
int               err = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &up);
if (err != 0)
    HandleError();
uint64_t      uptime_nano = up.tv_sec * 1000000000 + up.tv_nsec;
```

Time returned by this method does NOT include sleep / suspend states.

---

**OS X, older FreeBSD, Linux and Android**:

```
struct timeval  boot;
int             mib[] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_BOOTTIME };
size_t          size = sizeof(boot);
int             err = sysctl(mib, 2, &boot, &size, 0, 0);
if (err != 0)
    HandleError();
struct timeval  now;
err = gettimeofday(&now, 0);
if (err != 0)
    HandleError();
uint64_t        uptime_micro = (now.tv_sec * 1000000 + now.tv_usec) - (boot.tv_sec * 1000000 + boot.tv_usec);
```

This method is subject to races, as long as calculation requires two calls.

Mac also offers `mach_absolute_time()` function, but its behavior could come as unexpected: it counts first 30 seconds of sleep, and then stops counting.